# REST vs AMF for JavaScript single page application

Tags: javascript, python, django, rest, amf

I know differences between amf and rest, but i'm not sure, which technology will be easier and faster to implement. Can I get a hint from people who recently implemented apps using those?

I come from Flex background and had been using BlazeDS. I'm not sure which features of communication via BlazeDS should be attributed to BlazeDS and which to AMF. I know when using BlazeDS there were no problems with complex object trees and lazy loading, but does the same apply to pure AMF libraries like PyAMF? What about django rest framework?

Especially I would like to know:

- what JS amf library is most comprehensive and least problematic ?
- how much effort is required on js client and Django server to implement serialization/deserialization to/from REST? Compared to AMF it has to be much bigger effort AFAIK, unless there are proper tools. Which js library will do that for me?
- how does complex object trees influence serialization/deserialization effort. Does PyAMF has problems with that or does it work "out of the box"?
- how lazy loaded properties are handled? I believe AMF should be easier to use regarding that also.

Looking forward to your answers, because much of further work depends on them.

Regards,
okrutny